# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly System.Web in Mono for Android

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, onedrive

I'm building an android app with Xamarin that uses [SkyDrive .Net API Client](http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/) but I'm getting the following error when trying to run my android app on the emulator

```
Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Web.dll'
  at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 assemblies, Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  (MyApp)
```

Apparently i cannot use the System.Web assembly in Xamarin.Android. So, the question is if there is a way to load the missing assembly or i have to move to another API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you compiled the client from source or just got it in binary form?

I suppose you got it already compiled, so it's a library naming difference between Xamarin and MS .net, there is no System.Web.dll (but nearly all the classes exists inside the System.Web namespace but they are on other libraries).

The solution is to download the client's source code, inside Xamarin Studio in your same solution add a new Android Library project, add all the code files from the client to that project, add any necessary reference and reference that project in your main project, in this way the correct libraries will be linked (if no class is missing, as I said there are barely all, but not all).

Comment: I already download the source code and add the DLL project, then as you said i added all the code files from client to the project, but i cannot reference the client because it has a different target framework. Do you know where can i change the framework version of my project? thanks

Comment: You are doing it wrong, you cannot use the downloaded project, you must create a new Android library project and add all the classes there